# Rollup, multiple files, same constants name in multiple files: error in browser: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'o' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, constants, minify, rollupjs, terser

I have a problem.

#### EXPLANATION

In a website I navigate on page /one, the code in the *one.js* file executes fine.

After a while I insert in the page (pjax, ajax: no matter how) the second code in *two.js* file.

The browser complains with this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'o' has already been declared
- at two.js:1
```

#### REPRODUCTION and SOURCE CODE

1. *rollup.config.js*:

   ```js
   import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
   import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
   import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'
   import multiInput from 'rollup-plugin-multi-input'

   export default {
     input: ['src/**/*.js'],
     output: {
       format: 'esm',
       dir: 'dist/js'
     },
     plugins: [
       multiInput({ relative: 'src' }),
       resolve({ browser: true }),
       commonjs(),
       terser()
     ]
   }
   ```
2. *src/one.js*:

   ```js
   const names1 = ['john1', 'carl1', 'bob1']
   names1.forEach(name1 => {
     console.log('name1:', name1, ', in names1:', ...names1)
   })
   ```
3. *src/two.js*:

   ```js
   const names2 = ['john2', 'carl2', 'bob2']
   names2.forEach(name2 => {
     console.log('name2:', name2, ', in names2:', ...names2)
   })
   ```
4. *dist/js/one.js*:

   ```js
   const o=["john1","carl1","bob1"];o.forEach(n=>{console.log("name1:",n,", in names1:",...o)});
   ```
5. *dist/js/two.js*:

   ```js
   const o=["john2","carl2","bob2"];o.forEach(n=>{console.log("name2:",n,", in names2:",...o)});
   ```

#### QUESTIONS

How to fix this problem?

Can we "prefix" constants name based on file name?

If of course I put everything in just *one.js* file it works but it's not possible because of the structure of the project.

Comment: @Bergi sorry, fixed. It's "o".

Comment: @Bergi, what do you mean? How would you do it?

Comment: Oh, I was misguided. No block scopes necessary. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose `output.format: 'esm'`, which makes Rollup assume that the codes live in their own module scope. If you insert them in your page with

```
 <script type="module" src="/dist/js/one.js"></script>
 <script type="module" src="/dist/js/two.js"></script>
```

I would expect them to work. If you don't want to use `type="module"`, then use a different output format for Rollup which will wrap them in a module pattern (or IIFE) to give them their own scopes.

Comment: I never understood the format options. If I remove it Rollup tells me: `Error: You must specify "output.format", which can be one of "amd", "cjs", "system", "esm", "iife" or "umd".` But if I chose either "iife" or "umd" it bothers me with: `Error: UMD and IIFE output formats are not supported for code-splitting builds.`, with "esm" I need to use what you said (what it means `type="module"`?), the other ones are: "amd", "cjs", "system", what to choose? Differences?

Comment: I tried with cjs, it works, but where can I find a explained description for all of them?

Comment: @FredHors : see  https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputformat . Also I think that error you get with IIFE/UMD may be because you are using dynamic imports.